# Window object in nativescript

Tags: iframe, nativescript

I need to create a window object so that the external file, which is loaded inside iframe, can call nativescript function.

I, specifically need window object because the file I am loading can be any file that follows conformant (SCORM) related to LMS.

**Edit** :
The file I have loaded is a SCORM conformant file. They search for window.API object/window.parent.API and so on, for starting communication with the container in which they have been loaded. I can't alter that file.

Tell me if more details needed.

Comment: Please comment why downvote?

Comment: `window` in browsers is how the global javascript object is named, it exposes certain objects and functions which are only valid in the context of browsers and nowhere else. There is no `window` in nativescript, neither are there iframes. If you wish to mock certain functionality, creating a `global.window` property is totally fine. Also, a more specific description of what you are trying to achieve will allow us to give you pointers on where to look.

Comment: Thanks @pkanev, Can you share link so that I can refer it.

Comment: Check out the web view feature of NS.  https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view.  As @pkanev stated please provide more information on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this possible with nativescript?

Comment: hey @pkanev Is there anything I can do with 'addJavascriptInterface' method ?? I have installed http://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-webview-interface plugin. I am new to nativescript any help would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: That question would best be directed to the plugin author. I have not used the `nativescript-webview-interface` plugin.

Comment: Based on what I saw in ```nativescript-webview-interface```, you have a collection of methods to send events, receive events and run javascript functions. So, forget iframes no iframes in native. Use the webview and the plugin methods to communicate with your content.

Comment: Hi @RogersSampaio, as I said I can't modify the content I am loading. So, I have found a way to do this by adding a file(index.html) between the content and nativescript webview and loaded content in iframe of that file. And, also added plugin's communication method inside that file. Now I am able to create window object also. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0):

We are successfully handling SCORM content in our NativeScript application, but it does require a little bit of hackery to accomplish.

I authored a utility class that will inject into the main entry file (index) of the SCORM content an override for the window API.

Background:

- In our app we decompress the zip courses to the devices: documents/courses/UUID (that's what identity is referencing)
- You can change the path as needed for your implementation

Example usage of the utility class:

```
const documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
const destination = fs.path.join(documents.path, 'courses', this.media.identity);
this._readAccessUrl = destination;
const src = `file://${destination}`;
if (fs.File.exists(destination)) {
    SCORMUtils.readSCORMManifest(this.media.identity).then(fileName => {
        this._src = `${src}/${fileName}`;
        SCORMUtils.makeOfflineCompatible(fs.path.join(destination, fileName))
            .then(() => {
                this._loading = false;
            });
        this._loading = false;
    });
}
```

Utility Class:

```
import { File, knownFolders } from 'tns-core-modules/file-system';

const SCORM_API = `
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        window.parent.API = (function() {
            return {
                LMSInitialize: function () {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSInitialize");
                    }
                    return "true";
                },
                LMSCommit: function () {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSCommit");
                    }
                    return "true";
                },
                LMSFinish: function () {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSFinish");
                    }
                    return "true";
                },
                LMSGetValue: function (key) {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSGetValue");
                    }
                    return "";
                },
                LMSSetValue: function (key, value) {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSSetValue");
                    }
                    return "true";
                },
                LMSGetLastError: function () {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSGetLastError");
                    }
                    return "0";
                },
                LMSGetErrorString: function (errorCode) {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSGetErrorString");
                    }
                    return "No error";
                },
                LMSGetDiagnostic: function (errorCode) {
                    if (window && window.webkit) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage("LMSGetDiagnostic");
                    }
                    return "No error";
                }
            }
        })();
    })();
    </script>
    </head>
`;

export class SCORMUtils {

    /**
     * Converts a SCORM course to be opened offline
     * @param entryFile The main entry point determined by imsmanifest.xml
     */
    static makeOfflineCompatible(entryFile: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Rewrite the entry file first
            this._rewriteFile(entryFile)
                .then(() => {
                    this._discoverHTMLEntry(entryFile)
                        .then(() => {
                            resolve();
                        }, () => {
                            console.error('Unable to rewrite alternative HTML entry');
                            reject();
                        });
                }, () => {
                    console.error(`Unable to rewrite primary entry point: ${entryFile}`);
                    reject();
                });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Digests a SCORM Manifest file to determine the main point of entry
     * for the course viewer. Normally this is a index.html file.
     */
    static readSCORMManifest(identity: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const manifestFile = knownFolders.documents()
                .getFolder('courses')
                .getFolder(identity)
                .getFile('imsmanifest.xml');
            if (!File.exists(manifestFile.path)) {
                alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Course is missing imsmanifest.xml file',
                    okButtonText: 'Ok'
                });
                return reject();
            }
            const data = manifestFile.readTextSync(() => {
                alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Cannot open course.',
                    okButtonText: 'Ok'
                });
                return reject();
            });
            const matches = data.match(/type="webcontent"+.+?href="(.*?)"/);
            if (matches === null || matches.length < 1) {
                alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Invalid imsmanifest.xml file',
                    okButtonText: 'Ok'
                });
            }
            else {
                resolve(matches[1]);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Rewrites a file to be SCORM offline-compliant
     * @param path The path of the file to re-write
     */
    private static _rewriteFile(path: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const entryFile = File.fromPath(path);
            entryFile.readText()
                .then(htmlText => {
                    this._injectOfflineAPI(htmlText)
                        .then(updatedHtml => {
                            entryFile.writeText(updatedHtml).then(() => {
                                resolve();
                            }, () => {
                                console.error(`Error writing to file: ${path}`);
                                reject();
                            });
                        });
                }, () => {
                    console.error(`There was an entry reading the entry file at: ${path}`);
                    reject();
                });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to find another SCORM entry point for re-write
     * @param mainEntry The main entry point to branch from
     */
    private static _discoverHTMLEntry(mainEntry: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const entryFile = File.fromPath(mainEntry);
            entryFile.readText()
                .then(htmlText => {
                    let htmlEntry = htmlText.match(/{"type":"html5","url":"(.*?)"}/);
                    if (htmlEntry === null || htmlEntry.length < 1) {
                        // Check for Articulate
                        htmlEntry = htmlText.match(/location\.href\.replace\("index_lms", "(.*?)"/);
                    }
                    if (htmlEntry !== null && htmlEntry.length > 0) {
                        let fileName = htmlEntry[1];
                        if (fileName.indexOf('.html') === -1) {
                            fileName = `${fileName}.html`;
                        }
                        const directory = mainEntry.substr(0, mainEntry.lastIndexOf('/'));
                        const entryPoint = `${directory}/${fileName}`;
                        if (File.exists(entryPoint)) {
                            this._rewriteFile(entryPoint)
                                .then(() => {
                                    resolve();
                                }, () => {
                                    console.error('Error discovering main entry point.');
                                    reject();
                                });
                        }
                        else {
                            console.error(`Cannot find alternative entry point: ${entryPoint}`);
                            reject();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // This course does not have an alternative entry point
                        console.error('Course does not have an alternative entry, skipping...');
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, () => {
                    reject();
                });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Injects the extended SCORM API for offline-compatible viewing
     * @param text The unmodified HTML source text
     */
    private static _injectOfflineAPI(text: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Prevent multiple rewrites of the same file
            if (this._isConverted(text)) {
                return resolve(text);
            }
            // Finds the end of the head tag for script injection
            const head = text.match(/<\/head>/gi);
            if (head !== null && head.length > 0) {
                resolve(text.replace(head.toString(), SCORM_API));
            }
            else {
                console.error('Unable to parse incoming HTML for head tag.');
                reject({
                    message: 'Unable to parse HTML'
                });
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the HTML has already been converted for offline-viewing
     * @param text The incoming HTML source text
     */
    private static _isConverted(text: string) {
        const match = text.match(/window.parent.API/);
        return match !== null && match.length > 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @Sean How are you communicating data, like say LMSGetValue is triggered.

Comment: The WKWebView implementation allows for listening to messages being emitted from the frame: https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webkit-webview/blob/master/src/webkit-webview.ios.ts#L384. We personally haven't hooked into those yet, but I added those postMessage hooks for the future implementations.

Comment: I have installed market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-webview-interfa‌​ce plugin which helps me to communicate and return value from nativescript side.